# call private parameters in other private function inside the class c++

Tags: c++, private

Hello I have two questions. First, here is some code. I am new to c++. I have to calculate the square of rectangle by the  x,y coordinates of upper left and lower right corner - downRightx, upperLeftx, downRighty, upperLefty, the diagonal, and the sides of rectangle. I must make a function print() that calls other private functions only to show the result. Everything is defined inside the class.

```
class rectangle {
private:
    double uLx, uLy, dRx, dRy;
public:
    rectangle() {
        cout << "enter x coordinate of upper left corner" << uLx;
        cout << "enter y coordinate of upper left corner" << uLy;
        cout << "enter x coordinate of down right corner" << dRx;
        cout << "enter y coordinate of down right corner" << dRy;
    }
    ~rectangle() {
        cout << "Deleting object" << endl;
    }
private:
    void sides() {
        double a, b;

        a = sqrt(pow((dRx - uLx), 2));
        b = sqrt(pow((dRy - uLy), 2));
    }
    void facediag() {
        double s, d;
        d = sqrt(pow((dRx - uLx), 2) + pow((dRy - uLy), 2));
    ----    1. //here must be the calculation of square  s = a*b
    }
public:
    void print() {
    --- 2.  //here I must print the results
    }
};
```

so the question is: How to call `a` and `b` parameters from side in `facediag()` function to calculate `s = a*b` And how to print the results. Can I write `cout << a; cout << d; cout << s`, etc. in `sides()` and `facediag()` and just call them in `print`? Or can I print them in `print()` without writing `cout << ...` in other functions, but otherwise, another access method.

```
void facediag(){
   //code

    cout << s;
    cout << d;
    }
    void sides(){
      // code
    cout << a;
    cout << b;
    }
    void print()
    {
      sides();
      facediag();
    }// not like this, is there another way?
```

Second question I let Cygwin to be installed at its complete form and at some point I realized that I will run out of hdd and the installation hangs, so I interrupted  the installation. How can I uninstall it - just delete the folder or to step through the FAQ in the Cygwin site?

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: Local variables are local. You already know about member variables, so apply that knowledge to this problem. (Note that `sqrt(pow((dRx - uLx), 2));` is a pretty pointless operation.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access local variables from other functions. They only exist while that function executes.

What you *can* do is define more member functions that compute the values you need, like

```
double height() const
{ return /* something */; }

double width() const
{ return /* something else */; }
```

and use those functions where you need `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN call the private function in your OWN class.

But, the variable `a` and `b` are local variables, so they will not exist out of the function `sides()`, you can do the same thing in function `facediag()` to calculate `a` and `b`